# BulkAll only works with default mapping

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I am trying to use the BulkAll() method to add documents to my index.

The index is created using a mapping which works using IndexMany():

```
client.CreateIndex(indexName, c => c
                .Settings(s => s
                    .NumberOfShards(shardCount).NumberOfReplicas(replicaCount))
                .Mappings(ms => ms
                    .Map<MyDocument>(m => m.AutoMap())
            ));
```

I then try to use BulkAll():

```
Console.WriteLine("Indexing documents into elasticsearch...");
var waitHandle = new CountdownEvent(1);

var bulkAll = client.BulkAll(docsToUpload, b => b
    .Index(indexName)
    .BackOffRetries(2)
    .BackOffTime("30s")
    .RefreshOnCompleted(true)
    .MaxDegreeOfParallelism(4)
    .Size(100)
);

bulkAll.Subscribe(new BulkAllObserver(
    onNext: (b) => { Console.Write("."); },
    onError: (e) => { throw e; },
    onCompleted: () => waitHandle.Signal()
));

waitHandle.Wait();
Console.WriteLine("Done.");
```

This logs out a row of "....." followed by "Done" as expected, but my index is empty when I check it.

If I don't do the first step of creating the index then the bulk upload creates an index with default mappings, but I can't use it without my mappings.

Comment: What do you see if you look at `DebugInformation` (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/debug-information.html), or log out the requests (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/logging-with-on-request-completed.html)?

Comment: I wasn't able to find the debug info on an observable, but logging out the responses solved it. The type of docsToUpload passed in to the method is a supertype of the actual type of the docs (and mapping). This worked with `IndexMany()`, putting the mapped subtype in the index, but with `BulkAll()` it errored, saying I was trying to put a second type into the index.